# Stored function not firing in "insert into" subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Im using SQL on ORACLE 11g to insert into `table1` and at the same time fire a stored function that inserts into `table3`. The stored functions are not firing, I suspect this is because the ORACLE optimiser realises that the stored functions are not required by the insert into `table1` so it ignores them? 
Is there a way to request oracle does not optimize the query or is there a better solution.
Sample code:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1)
SELECT A.col1
FROM (SELECT col1, storedFunction(col2),storedFunction(col3),storedFunction(col4)
FROM table2) A
```

Comment: Have you tried to insert all data previously into a temporary table?

Comment: What *EXACTLY* are you trying to do? Call a procedure multiple times over a set of records or insert into multiple tables simultaneously?

Comment: danhip - That is a possability, but im inserting >100 Million rows so i wanted (if possible) to do it in 1 query

Comment: Adam - To add to my sample code. The storedProcedure is called multiple times, each time it inserts into table3

Comment: First, I'm assuming that it's really a stored function, not a stored procedure, since a stored procedure can't be called in a SQL statement.  But a stored function that does an insert into another table also wouldn't be eligible to be called from a SQL statement.  That implies that your stored function is declared using an autonomous transaction which introduces a bunch of wrinkles, none of them good.  Committing for every row you insert into `table3` is going to be hugely expensive.  Your stored function won't be able to see your session's uncommitted changes.  Is that what's going on?

Comment: Justin - Your correct it is a stored function, apologies for the confusion, and it is an autonomous transaction.

Comment: Justin - To add, I don't think the problem is uncommitted changes because the stored function insert is not dependant on the insert into table1

Comment: @DS: Can't you use a row trigger on table1 doing the call to storedFunction()? This would also save you the hassle of doing automous transactions and committing inside storedFunction.

Comment: GWu - I can't do that. There are other programs inserting into table1 that don't want the storedFunction to fire

Answer (score 2):

You could let your stored-procedure return `NULL` and use the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1)
SELECT NVL( col1, storedProcedure(col2) )
FROM table2
```

`NVL` always evaluates both parameters, even if the first one is not null.

I'm not sure if I would feel comfortable with this hack though...

Comment: Peter -  Unfortunately it's not my stored procedure and it returns a number, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You could wrap that function with your own function returning NULL, but as Adam said, try to rethink that strategy...

Answer (score 1):

Given that your `storedFunction` works as an autonomous transaction, and you are processing >100 Million rows, you are probably going to have *serious* performance problems. If at all possible, I would rethink this entire strategy. Scrap it. Start over.

**Option 1**

If this isn't possible, your best bet is to perform `bulk collect` fetches (with a limit) to retrieve `col1` and `col2`, calling `storedFunction` explicitly for each row's `col2`, then `bulk insert` into `table1`. This should hopefully minimize I/O on reads from `table2` and writes to `table1`. You're really going to pay the piper on calls to `storedFunction` though.

**Option 2**
Wrap your function inside another one which has the behavior you want. You didn't mention the types, but I'm assuming VARCHAR2. You can adjust as needed, of course. *Please excuse syntax errors as I do not have an Oracle database handy.*

```
CREATE FUNCTION MYFUNC(col1 IN VARCHAR2, col2 IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   v_dummy VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  v_dummy := storedFunction(col2);   --Call stored function
  return col1;                       --return col 1 unchanged
END;
```

Then you can do the insert as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1)
SELECT MYFUNC(A.col1, A.col2)
FROM   table2 A;
```

Comment: Adam = I realise i can use PL/SQL to do it. I was just surprised when it didn't work in SQL and i wondered if anyone had a 1 query SQL solution. Im stuck with the storedFunction though.

Comment: I'm just horrified by a function which uses autonomous transactions. *Shudder*

Answer (score 1):

The SQL solution is to make the subquery a temporary table and use the `/*+ MATERIALIZE */` hint in the subquery to force Oracle to evaluate the stored Functions.
e.g.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1)
WITH temp_table AS (/*+ MATERIALIZE */  SELECT col1, storedFunction(col2),storedFunction(col3),storedFunction(col4)
FROM table2) 
SELECT col1
FROM temp_table
```